# Android - Can't open emulator window

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

Whenever I start my emulator from Eclipse it loads, but I CANNOT open the window to actually see and interact with the emulator?

I can only view it from the taskbar but I cannot actually open it. When I click it in the taskbar, nothing happens. It's not behind my windows or anything.

This is all I can do https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH7eA.png

Any solution to this?

Comment: Sometimes, when the emulator is loading, the windows is not responding. It should become available afterwards. Did you try to wait for 1-2 minutes to finish loading and try again?

Comment: do you see something in the logcat? if you kill the process and start it again the same happens? do you wait long enough (the emulator needs a while to start)?

Comment: Maybe it has moved out of bounds of your Desktop. Try right-clicking it and selecting the move function. Or if you were using an extended display, turn it off using WinKey + P.

Comment: If it's a new emulator you are starting, it might take a few minutes before it actually starts. Depending on your computer specifications, it can take a minute or 2 to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following **[these steps](http://androidbook.blogspot.co.il/2011/03/tip-speeding-up-your-android-emulator.html)**:

Try to create a new AVD and **make sure the SD card is large enough**, 200mb should be fine.
Also **check the snapshot option** (saves the state of the emulator, and makes it load faster).
Sometimes the emulator won't run unless you check **Wipe User Data** or uncheck **Launch from snapshot** option.

Try different configuration. It also takes quite some time for the emulator to load, depending on you hardware's capabilities, so be patient (give it 10 min to see if it really freezes).

Comment: The 200mb sd card option seemed to work for some reason. Thanks